# Acesso a arrays de outras funções HTML

Tags: html, array

tenho este código:

```
    function shuffle(array) {
    var counter = array.length, temp, index;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
    // Pick a random index
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;

     // And swap the last element with it
        temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    return array;
    }
```

E depois tenho isto:

```
function somethingOne(){
  shuffle(array);
  ... 
}
```

O meu objetivo é criar uma função `somethingTwo()` que usa o array que foi baralhado na função `somethingOne()`, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Mas o que você quer fazer nesta função? Onde a função será chamada?

Comment: Tenho um baralho de cartas, onde o array são as 52 imagens... Eu na função somethingOne() baralho as cartas, e entrego 13 cartas a cada "jogador" ... O que eu queria era numa função por exemplo somethingTwo() ordenar a "mão" de cada jogador, ou seja, ordenar as cartas de cada jogador... Percebe o que eu quero dizer?

Comment: E para isso preciso de aceder ás cartas que foram baralhadas na função somethingOne()

Answer (score 1):

```
function somethingOne(){
  shuffle(array);
  ... 
}
```

Para aceder ao Array fora de uma funcao o mesmo tera que ter Criado fora ou seja

```
Var array; // Fora de qualquer Funcao!
```

// Depois as funcoes aqui poderam utilizar o mesmo Array criado em cima.

```
    function somethingOne(){
      array = shuffle(array);
      ... 
   }
```

Assim o Array ficara baralhado em todo programa.

Answer (score 0):

Se a variável passara para a função for global, você pode acessá-la em qualquer local, mesmo após a função ser chamada.

Se não é global, você pode fazer algo como `var algo = funcao(argumento);` e usar a variável que recebeu o retorno da função.

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma boa prática utilizar variáveis globais por **n** motivos. Talvez a melhor maneira para esse caso seria trabalhar com um objeto literal. Veja:

```
var obj = {
  arr: [],
  suffle: function ( someArray ) 
  {
    someArray.push('foo');
  },
  somethingOne: function () 
  {
     // use o operador this para acessar os metodos e atributos
     this.suffle( this.arr );
  },
  somethingTwo: function() {
    this.somethingOne();
    console.log(this.arr);
  }
};
obj.somethingTwo(); // ['foo']
```